# Run-time errors in case expressions of SML

Tags: sml

I was studying about `pattern matching` in `SML`. I came across with the following saying:

> `case` expressions in `SML` can get compile errors and run-time errors.

I know how to create a compile error with `case`, but how to create run-time errors?

Comment: `raise Fail "This is a run-time error"`

Answer (score 0):

That can happen in the presence of nonexhaustive matching:

```
datatype directions = North | South | East | West

fun turn d = case d of
  North => East
 |East => South
 |South => West
```

This compiles (albeit with: `Warning: match nonexhaustive`). But then:

```
turn West
```

will trigger the run-time error:

```
uncaught exception Match [nonexhaustive match failure]
```

I can't think of a run-time error in a `case` statement that wouldn't have at least triggered a warning (other than the trivial way in which the expression that comes after the `=>` in one of the cases could itself throw an error).

Comment: An SML compiler is indeed required to issue a warning for non-exhaustive matches (except for top-level interactive val declarations). And there are no other possible failures for a match.